# Update options value on OpenCart order page

Tags: php, opencart

Using OpenCart as an ecommerce solution I'm trying to edit the cart page so that I can update option values in addition to quantity and have run into a bit of trouble.

My current code takes the correct option that's been chosen and puts it in a select box. Here's the code:

```
<?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option) { ?>
      <div style="float: left; width: 100px;">
        <select style=" text-align: left;" class="storeitems" name="option[<?php echo $option['option_id']; ?>]" selected="<?php echo $option['value']; ?>">
        <option>
         <?php echo $option['value']; ?>              
        </option>
        </select>
      </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Now, I need it to pull in the other options (as seen on the proudct page).  Here is that code:

```
<select style="max-width: 145px;" class="storeitems" name="option[<?php echo $option['option_id']; ?>]" selected="<?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>">
        <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $option_value['option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>

          </option>
        <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: where is the problem i can't understand what's wrong here ??

Answer (score 0):

In your second piece of code you have no product identification so opencart doesn't know what product to display options for.